# Set nomodeset in usb installation (efi loader with iso)

Tags: iso, uefi, nomodeset

I'm working with [the studyblast solution](http://studyblast.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/guide-mac-os-x-lion-how-to-boot-a-linux-live-system-from-a-usb-drive-how-to-update-any-ocz-ssds-firmware/) to creating a live USB on OS X. I managed to get Ubuntu booted but the screen looks like a corrupt/glitch image. I can just about make out the clock on the bottom right and a few icons. I've been told that this is easily fixed and that `nomodeset` needs to be set for the graphics card. But all the solutions I find are for Ubuntu systems installed to hard drives. Where you can cd in and edit the grub file - how do you do this is if it's in an iso?

Comment: This should be of help to you.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation

Answer (score 0):

The following instructions are from [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Ubuntu_CD_Advanced_Welcome_Page_Options)  :

As the CD boots, the user can gain access to the advanced page and its options by **pressing any key** when the small logo appears at the bottom of your screen:

[image: logoscreen]

Here is the Advanced welcome page:

[image: Welcome screen]

Hit `F6` to get Other Options, and choose `nomodeset` from the dropdown menu.

Comment: Hi, thanks I had attempted to do that but the screen is corrupt right the way through the process so I can't see what I'm doing via any graphical interface.  I have found another installation solution now using this method (http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/dual-boot-os-ubuntu/) which worked for me.