# error when starting install

Tags: system-installation

First of all, I'm completely clueless, so I hope this is all the info I should include.

I have a Toshiba Qosmio X70-A-12U that came with a pre-installed Windows 8. I have used it like that for a while and now I want to replace it with Ubuntu (not install Ubuntu alongside it), but I get errors immediately after I select Install and then nothing happens, I don't even hear the DVD spinning anymore.

When I turn on the power, I get to this screen (which doesn't exactly look like the [screenshot](http://assets.ubuntu.com/sites/ubuntu/1532/u/img/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop/image-installdesktoplongtermsupport-1.jpg) from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop), but at least I see the try and install options):

[image: first screen]

[image: first screen options detail]

Then I select Install and get this for a split second:

[image]

> `0.039324] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)`
>
> `4.216205] ACPI PCC probe failed`

Then the DVD keeps spinning for a little while until it stops, the screen freezes like this and ultimately my laptop abruptly shuts down.

[image]

This happens both with Ubuntu 15.04 and 14.04.3 LTS.

---

UPDATE:

Following the instructions in the comments, the first line (`Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)`) is now gone. The other two still appear and the final result is the same.

Comment: You can try to disable fastboot, uefi in bios and run installer again.

Comment: @bnz I have disabled UEFI (switched to CMS) and now I go through the second screen from here http://askubuntu.com/questions/525280/how-to-install-ubuntu-in-a-pre-installed-windows-8-1-64-bit-without-uefi/525287#525287 not the first anymore, but the end result is the same.

Comment: I’m not an Ubuntu expert but from the log messages it looks like a problem related to your GPU, although those messages are not strict errors and the system should be able to boot.

In case you have access to the boot options the following is worth a try as it instructs the kernel to not load video drivers until X is loaded.

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"`

Good luck!

Comment: @LarsBeck Did the `nomodeset` thing as here http://askubuntu.com/questions/135515/set-nomodeset-in-usb-installation-efi-loader-with-iso/135539#135539 - same result

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about your Toshiba model, but mine has a Fingerprint reader that supposedly encrypts the Hdd. I disable it before installing an OS. If I were you, I'd also try it before installing it and see if (and how) that works.

Finally, I keep a dual boot of win 10 and Kali on my older tablet hybrid. On the newer one, with ssd, I keep Kali on an encrypted USB key and use mostly Win 10. I applaud your courage to go Ubuntu fully, completely.